# How to set onCollisionEnter on a object?

Tags: lua, tabletop-simulator

I'm using Atom get script my TTS mod. In my game I have a bag with GUID `ed743f` I have a Global file that calls my `#include Shard/shard` file. In that file I have `#include diceroller` in my `diceRoller.ttslua` file I have this code:

```
diceRoller = getObjectFromGUID("ed743f")
  print(diceRoller, 'roller')

function onCollisionEnter()
  print('dice entered')
end
```

The print works so the file is included correctly but how do "connect" the onCollisionEnter function with the correct object (diceRoller)? Because now when I put a die in the bag nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Piglet is correct by saying onCollisionEnter(...) does not work in Global. What I did was right click the object (bag) in Tabletop Simulator and hit "Scripting editor". This opens the script file for that object. Then in that file I made a require reference `require("somefolder/somefile")`. The root of the path is:

> C:\Users*****\Documents\Tabletop Simulator

So now I can use onCollisionEnter(...) because the script is not Global but object bound.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

onCollisionEnter(...)

> This function is called when an Object starts colliding with the
>   Object the function is on. Does not work in Global.

The function is on means that it is implemented in the Object Script of that object.

Object members:

> `script_code` The Lua Script on the Object.
>
> **Object Script** A script that is attached to an in-game Object, and is
>   saved as part of it. This is similar to any other property like its
>   scale or tint. Some functions ask for an Object reference in order to
>   attempt to run a function on it. In these cases, Global (exactly as
>   written here) is also a valid Object reference.

From what I read here I'd say you need to implement that function in your objects script.

Please read the manual again.

https://api.tabletopsimulator.com/event/